# Difference between DataTable.Load() and DataTable = dataSet.Tables[];

Tags: c#, .net

I have a doubt  i use the following piece of code get data from a SQLlite data base and Load it into a data table

```
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path);

cnn.Open();

SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
string sql = "select Company,Phone,Email,Address,City,State,Zip,Country,Fax,Web from RecordsTable";
mycommand.CommandText = sql;

SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();

dt.Load(reader);

reader.Close();

cnn.Close();
```

In some cases when I try to load it Gives me "Failed to enable constraints exception"

But when I tried this below given piece of code for same table and same set of records it worked

```
SQLiteConnection ObjConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path);

SQLiteCommand ObjCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select Company,Phone,Email,Address,City,State,Zip,Country,Fax,Web from RecordsTable", ObjConnection);
ObjCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SQLiteDataAdapter ObjDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(ObjCommand);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

ObjDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "RecordsTable");

dt = dataSet.Tables["RecordsTable"];
```

Can any one tell me what is the difference between two

Comment: Sounds like the SQLlite implementation of the "Load" method has a bug. Report it to http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodotnetsqlite/.

In the SQL Server edition the "Load" method also has performance issues. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=95318&wa=wsignin1.0, so I've not used it in my code, for consistance when moving between data providers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Load() method purposefully evaluates constraints, whereas simply pulling out a DataTable from the Dataset by index does not.  That's the difference of interest in your case.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsze9wte(VS.80).aspx

Comment: That's the correct answer, see this comment for some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable/14807940#comment35409117_14807940 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229425/net-datatable-skips-rows-on-loaddatareader