# Returning a Dataset as an Object in a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing a method that will query a table and return a *Dataset* object containing the specified column. Moreover, I have a problem with my Username & Password, so I am using *Windows* authentication for the same but I am not too sure about that in my snippet I have written till now.

```
 protected void GetProgramList()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC/sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProgramName FROM Program", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();

    }
```

I have been trying to follow official MS documentation but I am not sure where I am going? Can someone help me with some links or snippets?

Comment: What you are looking for is explained here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say you have 2 options here:
1. to make a DataSet class variable, so its reference can be accessed from all over the class (set its access modifier to public so it can be accessed from other classes)
2. or create a method with its return type of DataSet. But in this case on the other side must be set to receive the DataSet as well:

//2. solution:

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        //from inside some method:
        DataSet ds = GetProgramList();
    }

    protected DataSet GetProgramList()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC/sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT ProgramName FROM Program", cn))
                da.Fill(ds1, "TableName1");
        }
        return ds1;
    }
    //


//1. solution:
class YourClass
{
    DataSet ds1;
    protected void GetProgramList()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC/sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProgramName FROM Program", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds1 = new DataSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: The mistake I am making here is, I am not returning anything, I am using a void method. What return type should I use for a Dataset?

Comment: DataSet return type of course - if you use my 2nd  solution! ... If you use my 1st solution you use void return type!!

Comment: One more question, what kind of variable type should I use to store the returned Dataset?

Comment: Again DataSet. Check my 2nd solution. Its all there!

Answer (score 2):

Place your connection string in AppSettings section in app.config or web.config

```
   public string GetSqlConnection()
    {
        return  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"];
    }



  public DataSet getDataSet(string sql)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetSqlConnection());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: "use" System.Data and System.Data.SqlClient, and use a "SqlDataReader":

- http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson04

Either read everything in your routine (generally preferred), or pass the SqlDataReader back to the caller (as a function return).

And be sure to .Close() the reader when you're done :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLDataAdapter basic](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter) will get you started with the basics of creating a connection and consuming it in your code.