# DataAdapter is disposed before reaching "End Using"

Tags: vb.net, idisposable, dataadapter

I know that I should always dispose DataAdapter instances. In most cases I'm disposing it immediately after closing the connection, but in cases like when user will be modifying DataTable items (displayed in ListBox or DataGridView) I create the DataAdapter, use it to fill the DataTable, but don't dispose it until the user clickes `Save` which calls `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)`... *not my main question but is this the right approach?*

Back to the main question, I have these two functions:

```
Public Function LoadCompaniesDT(ByRef dtCompanies As DataTable) As Boolean
    Using daCompanies As MySqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Return LoadCompaniesDT(daCompanies, dtCompanies)
    End Using
End Function

Public Function LoadCompaniesDT(ByRef daCompanies As MySqlDataAdapter, ByRef dtCompanies As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM companies"
    Return LoadDT(daCompanies, dtCompanies, sql, Res.CompaniesFailedMsgBody)
End Function
```

They're used to call `LoadDT` which fills the DataTable so I have the choice to pass a DataAdapter or not.

Now I'm confused about something: When using the first `LoadCompaniesDT` function, `daCompanies` is disposed before reaching `End Using`.. like this:

```
Public Function LoadCompaniesDT(ByRef dtCompanies As DataTable) As Boolean
    Using daCompanies As MySqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Dim tmp As Boolean = LoadCompaniesDT(daCompanies, dtCompanies)
        Console.WriteLine(daCompanies Is Nothing) ' ==> True!!
        Return tmp
    End Using
End Function
```

Note: if I use `Dim daCompanies` instead of `Using daCompanies` then `daCompanies Is Nothing` will return False.

---

`LoadDT` function code:

```
Private Function LoadDT(ByRef da As MySqlDataAdapter, ByRef dt As DataTable,
                                                      ByVal sqlQuery As String,
                                                      ByVal errorText As String) As Boolean
    Dim connStr As String = String.Format("server={0}; port={1}; user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}",
                                          DbServer, DbServerPort, DbUserName, DbPassword, DatabaseName)
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    Try
        conn.Open()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
        cmd.Connection = conn

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(errorText, Res.ServerError, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return False
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You should change the title to include `ByRef` because that is the core of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: you're right, you don't get an initialized  `MySqlDataAdapter` back from the methods if the `ByRef` passed instance is used in a `Using`-statement. Those variables are readonly. In C# you get [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf57d7ay.aspx) meaningful compiler error:

> Error CS1657  Cannot pass 'daCompanies' as a ref or out argument
>   because it is a 'using variable'

It's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf57d7ay.aspx):

> Compiler Error **CS1657**
>
> Cannot pass 'parameter' as a ref or out argument because 'reason''
>   This error occurs when a variable is passed as a ref or out argument
>   in a context in which that variable is readonly. Readonly contexts
>   include foreach iteration variables, using variables, and fixed
>   variables.

In VB.NET you can do that(so the compiler ignores it which is almost a bug)  but the variable is not initialized afterwards. But as mentioned below, you should not use this approach anyway.

---

According to the the other question:

If you look at the sample on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you'll see that microsoft also doesn't dispose the dataadapter. So it not really necessary. Having said that, it's always best practise to use the `Using` statement on anything that implements `IDisposable`.

A `DataAdapter` is not an expensive object and it does not hold unmanaged resources(like the connection). So it doesn't hurt to create a new instance from it whereever you need one. And you don't need to dispose it, but that's an implementation detail that might change in future or in a different implementation of `DbDataAdapter`, so it's still best practise to dispose it, best by using the `Using`-statement.

I wouldn't use your approach because you are passing the sql-string to the method which often leads to a sql injection vulnerabiliy. Instead use sql parameters.

For example:

```
Private Function LoadDT() As DataTable
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()
    'Load connection string from app.config or web.config
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM companies" ' don't use * but list all columns explicitely
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.MySqlConnection)
        Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
            da.Fill(tbl)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return tbl
End Function
```

Instead of passing an `errorText` `ByRef` i'd use a logging framework like [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial).

Comment: Yes, that's the impression I got from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18205560/4934172) question. So why does it get disposed before reaching the end of the `Using` statement?

Comment: I see. Thank you for your effort, that did help :)

Comment: I just noticed your note about using parameters, yes I do that but in this function I'm just loading the whole table (no `WHERE clause`) is there a problem with that? Also I don't understand what `SELECT * FROM` can lead to?

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN: i don't use parameters because they are not needed in this case. But by allowing a sql-string as parameter you allow also: `SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE ID='';DELETE FROM Tbl`. So it's just best practise to not building sql queries by concatenating string or passing them around. A sql query should always be a string constant. For example: `SELECT Col1 FROM tbl WHERE ID=@ID`

Comment: Here you'll find more informations why `SELECT *` is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) in production code.