# How to store one data column in array

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, double

I would like to know how can I store data in an array. The reason is because I am required to loop through the array, in order to detect any multiple data.

I have the code and tested it to run through for any multiple data in array and it works, but that array does not contain data from database. Right now I really need to store the column data in the database. This is my code.

```
double[] array1; // store the sql column data here.

int count=0;
bool maxreached=false;
for(int i=0;i<array1.Length;i++)
{
   if(array1[i]==text)
   count++;
   if(count>1)
   {
      maxreached=true;
      break;
   }
}   

if(maxreached)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Your array does not have any data in it because you are not putting any data in it. You are simply declaring an array and then checking the empty array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows this, he is asking how to get the data from the database and put it in the array. IMO, this is more worthy of a search on google than a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data from the sql-table, you should look at this: [Read SQL Table into C# DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable). once you have all your data in the datatable you can use a for loop to go through all the rows and columns using `Datatable.Row[i].Column[j]` where i and j are either numbers or strings(i will most likely be a number and j a string) and save the contents in your array

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop over the array data.  You can use the `Contains` method to search for a specific value.

```
// Load the data
double[] array1 = new double[] {
    1d,
    2d,
    3d,
    4d,
    5d
};

double searchValue = 5;

if (array1.Contains(searchValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found " + searchValue);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("*NOT* Found " + searchValue);
}
```