# C# - How to copy rows from table in SQL server and insert into DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a table in my Database to store Holidays.
The Columns:

```
Holiday, Day, Date
```

I want to copy all the rows from this table into a DataTable in my C# application. Iv created the DataTable with the same Columns.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {
            new DataColumn("Holiday", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Day", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime))
        });
```

How can I populate this DataTable with all of the rows from my SQL Server database?

Comment: with a SQL SELECT statement?  You dont need to define the DataTable, the db Provider will do that for you

Comment: As always, you could read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The answer to this question must be easily available as Michael McGiff notes above. Please do your research first. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read SQL Table into C# DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a Data Adapter to fill the datatable.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Holidays", sqlConn))
     {
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         da.Fill(dt);
     }
 }
```