# Dealing with implementing a Database to a Datatable

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

while I was trying to convert my Database to a Datatable, I found information about about how to add Columns to a Database. The Code looked a little like this:

```
string it;
DataTable another_tranTab = new DataTable();
another_tranTab.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(String)); 
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

while (a < tranTable.Rows.Count)
{
    it = Convert.ToString(tranTable.Rows[a][0]);
    if (it == "False")
    {
        DataRow newRow = another_tranTab.NewRow();
        newRow["Column1"] = a;
        another_tranTab.Rows.Add(newRow);
        b = b + 1;
    }
    a++;
}
```

My question is what this part stands for `it = Convert.ToString(tranTable.Rows[a][0]);`
I don't really understand what the `[0]` stands for.

Comment: I think [0] means column1 of datatable and a is the row of datatable.

Comment: Just curious if you are using ADO.net to query the data base you could use a SQLdataAdapter to fill a data table automatically unless there is some strange constraints on your data. Shown here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable

Comment: Rows[a][0]]- Rows[rowindex][Columnindex]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Columns     0          1               2 

           Name       City            Age

   Row 0   Guilherme  Pres. Prud.     23

   Row 1   Lucas      São Paulo       18

   Row 2   Pedro      Rio de Janeiro  35
```

How do I get city from Pedro?

I must get the line 2 and col 1.

```
Then: dataTable[1][2]. //dataTable[col1][row2].
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer was quite easier than I thought :) 
I am not quite sure what you mean with ADO.net, I am doing this with a Windows Form Application with Visual Studio (.NET). My actual goal is to fill a groupbox with buttons and each button shall stand for one entry from my Sql-Database which already exists