# ssis output json file adding extra crlf

Tags: json, sql-server, ssis, etl

This has been solved with c# code, please refer to this post [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059599/ssis-generate-json-file-remove-return/54084996#54084996)

I have package inside a ole db source to run a query to generate Json file for a flat file destination. The query: Note I have used replace to get rid of crlf if they do exist in the column activity (which i don't see)

```
SELECT  
Replace(Replace([activity], char(13),''), char(10),'') [activity]
FROM [CRM].[dbo].[JJVCACUProductElectron] for json auto
```

The generated json is with some crlf so can see multiple lines if viewed in notepad ++. And when paste the content into a online json parser, the format is invalid. After manually removing all the crlf from the generated josn file so the json data will be in one single line then the format is fine in the parser.

Is is weird that if I change the query to just return one record into the file then the json is fine. There is only 7 rows in the table, so I have tried every row and they all work, which makes me doubt if crlf really is the issue. But if without this column, then all the rows can be generated to json no issue.

I have tried the way of use a variable to store the content of the query then select the variable, this will work but for tables with a tens of millions of rows it will cause performance issue. So this will not be an option.

**In conclusion:**

1. I can't use the put the content into a variable then output method.
2. Removing crlf on the column seems not working, or there is indeed no crlf in the column.
3. Removing crlf from the generated text file will work. But where do these crlf coming from?

This is select activity from [the table]

[image]

This shows the generated json file, you can see there are two lines.

[image]

And a crlf at the end of the first line. if remove this crlf so there will be just one line, then the content is a valid json.

[image]

Comment: Is this related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059599/ssis-generate-json-file-remove-return

Comment: I think you should add this info to your other question and delete this one as this question is missing code and the other question is missing an explanation of the issue.

Comment: well i tried different approaches in desperate , the other question was one of them. This question is actually from a ole db source directly to a flat file target. Now I am thinking it's the sql server database engine actually adding the crlf at some point in the output json data. But I am not sure, because i have far larger json files generated no problem by the same method.

Comment: If you think that then you need to inspect it. Inspect the data at each point

Comment: Like I said  if I change the query to just return one record into the file then the json is fine.

Comment: 7 records will generate 7 crlf in an output file.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the output of the query *(with and without `for json auto`)*

Comment: @Hadi added screen shots