# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed in database layer

Tags: c#

I wrote method in my `database layer` to be consumed by other upper layers. This method returns `IDataReader` as shown below:

```
public IDataReader GetDataReader(string commandText, CommandType commandType, IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
     IDataReader reader = null;

     using (var connection = _database.GetConnection())   //either opens new or uses existing connection if exist
     {
           using (var command = _database.GetCommand(commandText, connection, commandType))
           {
               {
                   if (parameters != null)
                   {
                        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                        }
                   }
                   reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                   return reader;
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Now when i want to consume that method somewhere else and when it reaches while `(reader.Read())` it gave me an error.

```
private void GetResult()
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    var reader = Context.GetDataReader(query, CommandType.Text, null);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.'
```

What could i do to fix that?

Comment: don't return your reader. you should project that to something else first.

Comment: You're disposing the connection in `GetDataReader`, ergo, your database interaction is finished.

Comment: @rfmodulator that's what i suspect, nevertheless what could i do to overcome that and get my common method to return IDataReader?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, the question to what.

Comment: @Arie it depends on what you are doing in `GetResult`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I wanted to create common method "GetDataReader" to reduce the code in many places. I have lot of places like GetResult when i need datareader to get records and for each one of them. For instance in GetResult in while reader.read i want to loop through all records and do something there.

Comment: @Arie There is such a thing as too much abstraction! :)

Comment: @rfmodulator that's not helping :)

Comment: @Arie You may consider returning a `DataTable` instead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073545/1048799

Comment: @rfmodulator cannot datatable as it's too much data comming in therefore i pick up streamreader