# DataTable.Load(FbDataReader) does not load everything into DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, firebird

There is a closely related question here: [.NET DataTable skips rows on Load(DataReader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229425/net-datatable-skips-rows-on-loaddatareader)

I have a SQL Query that returns 169 results. The result looks like this:

```
CustomerID Customer Name TerminalID Creation Date
     1     First Customer   12345   2010-07-07
     1     First Customer   12346   2010-07-07
     1     First Customer   12347   2010-07-07
     2     Second Customer  23456   2011-04-18
```

This result is correct.

I entered the query in a C# program and execute it like this:

```
public DataTable getDataTableFromSql(FbCommand command)
{
    // Create a new datatable
    DataTable result = new DataTable();

    // Set up the connection
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(this.connectionString))
    {
        // Open the connection
        con.Open();

        // Set up the select command
        FbCommand sqlCmd = command;
        // Add the connection to it
        sqlCmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            // Get the results
            using (FbDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Load the results into the table
                result.Load(sqlReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    // Return the table
    return result;
}
```

This code is tested and it works fine for many different SQL queries.
But for the above query the `DataTable` only contains 39 results and looks like this:

```
CustomerID Customer Name TerminalID Creation Date
     1     First Customer   12347   2010-07-07
     2     Second Customer  23456   2011-04-18
```

I fiddled around with the code a bit and here's what I found out so far: The `FbDataReader` correctly fetches the results from the database. If I just query for the `TerminalID` I end up with 169 results in the `DataTable`. If I query for the `CustomerID` I recieve 39 results.

**Conclusion:** The line `result.Load(sqlReader)` groups the result for `CustomerID` and throws away all other results, no matter if they can be grouped or not.

Why is this happening? How can I load the result of my query into the `DataTable` without "losing" any rows due to unlogical grouping? And why does the `DataTable` "group" the result in the first place?

Note: I also tried all three `LoadOptions` available for `DataTables`, all with the same outcome: Only 39 results are loaded into the `DataTable`.

Comment: Have you tried to fill with dataadapter?

Comment: What means _" If I just query for the TerminalID"_? Where and how do you query it if you check the `DataTable` content?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That means I edit my SQL Query so that it returns only the Coloumn `TerminalId`. When I run the program again, I recieve all 169 results in the `DataTable`.

Comment: @waka: how many records does the `DataReader` return? Have you used an `int` variable in a loop(`while(sqlReader.Read()count++;)`) to see if the DB returns 39 or 169 records? Then you would at least know if your problem is related to `DataTable.Load` at all  or to the query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, I checked that. The `FbDataReader` works fine and returns all the results it should return. The problem is indeed related to `DataTable.Load()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET DataTable skips rows on Load(DataReader)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229425/net-datatable-skips-rows-on-loaddatareader)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataTable.Load` method expects a primary key column in the underlying data (i.e. from `DataReader`). Looks like your procedure does not have any primary key column, or if you have one please user `order by` in the sql statement so that the`DataTable` will able to accept it as primary.

This is an very old issue with `DataTable.Load` and not very well documented. In general `SQLDataAdapter` is good with `DataTable`.

In your case, I think as soon as Load finds a duplicate it stops loading data. I have not get this documented anywhere but looks like this the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Even if i don't know the problem i would suggest to use a `DataAdapter` instead. Maybe that works:

```
// Get the results
using(var da = new FbDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
{
    // Load the results into the table
    da.Fill(result);
}
```

---

Why that happened? I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210238/284240) in another question explains it.

Comment: I just tested this and I get 169 results in the `DataTable`, thanks! I really would love to know why `DataTable.Load()` seems to "swallow" some of the results... :/

Comment: @waka: here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229425/net-datatable-skips-rows-on-loaddatareader

Comment: Thanks, I think I now know what happens. I'll edit my question to include my thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

The soultion to the problem is as follows:

`DataTable.Load()` looks for a *Primary Key* in the results. If the *Primary Key* it tries to load into the `DataTable` already is present in that table, it overwrites the row with the new result.

However, using a different alias for the column with the *Primary Key* does solve the problem, all the results will get loaded into the `DataTable`, since it seems the information that this column is a *Primary Key* is overwritten by using an alias.