# C# & SQL Server stored procedure doesn't return results

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a zip from a database and I've written a stored procedure like this

```
[dbo].[p_SearchZipLocal]
    @zip nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @city nvarchar(100) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
        -- Verifica se o zip aparece na primeira coluna
        IF((SELECT COUNT(cttzip) 
            FROM seur 
            WHERE cttzip = @zip) > 0)
        BEGIN
            -- Verifica se o valor é NA, se não for devolve o zip e a localidade correcta
            IF((SELECT TOP(1) [SubCity1] as city 
                FROM seur 
                WHERE cttzip = @zip) = '#N/A')
            BEGIN
                -- Se for NA vamos ter de pesquisar na quinta coluna pela localidade
                IF((SELECT count(*) FROM seur WHERE subCity2 LIKE @city + '%' )>0)
                    -- Se encontrar-mos devolvemos o novo zip
                    SELECT TOP(1) 
                        '0' AS Error, subZip2 as zip, subCity2 AS city 
                    FROM seur 
                    WHERE subCity2 LIKE @city + '%'
                ELSE
                    SELECT 
                        '2' AS Error, 'Erro' AS zip, 'Erro' AS city
                END
            ELSE
                SELECT TOP(1) 
                    '0' AS Error, cttzip AS zip, [SubCity1] as city 
                FROM seur 
                WHERE cttzip = @zip
        END
    ELSE
        SELECT '1' AS Error, 'Erro' AS zip, 'Erro' AS city
    END
END
```

Returning the results when executed from SQL Server like this:

```
0   9900    AEROPORTO DA HORTA
```

But when I call it from C# code it doesn't return the results to the datatable.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p_SearchZipLocal", connectionSQL))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "9900";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "PRAIA DO ALMOXARIFE";

    connectionSQL.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

This code gets the column names in the return but there is no value associated. Can anyone tell me where is my code wrong?

Comment: Little tip, in your `if` checks, instead of doing `> 0` or `TOP (1) ... = ` use `Exists(` it will result in faster queries. [Here is your posted code rewritten to use it](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/acf29262b062f9071965). Also your `SELECT TOP(1)` section I think is wrong, you are doing a top 1 without a order by which is likely a error. You probably wanted another exist there (which I did in the example I linked to)

Comment: Your code worked well with some fine tunning. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would use .Fill with a DataAdapter

Please see this...

[DataTable.Load(FbDataReader) does not load everything into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663734/datatable-loadfbdatareader-does-not-load-everything-into-datatable)

Comment: The problem persists. I'm thinking the data doesn't pass from the sql stored procedure -> C#

Comment: Can you try something like this?

// comment out dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());  then add this:



SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
   while(myReader.Read()) 
   {
      Console.WriteLine(myReader["city"]);
   }
   myReader.Close();

Comment: Solved with a little of every tip. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The `DataTable.Load` method expects a primary key column in the underlying data (i.e. from DataReader). Look like your procedure not have any primary key column, or if you have one please user `order by` in sql statement and try to keep it as first column so that `DataTable` will able to accept it as primary.

This is very old issue with `DataTable.Load` and not very well documented. In general `SQLDataAdapter` is good with `DataTable`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem was directly correlated with not returning a primary key but it was one of the things I added to the final solution. Thanks for the help