# DataTable.Load shows less rows than source DataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have just noticed a strange behaviour in my ASP.NET application running both on MySQL and SQL Server.

The application issues plain SQL queries over an EF connection to build a dataset. The result set does not contain any primary surrogate key (the primary key is not part of the `SELECT` statement). Queries are very complex and I'm not allowed to show them, but I can explain very clearly what happens.

Given the query as

```
select a.A01, a.A01a, a.A01b, a.A02, a.A03, A11, A12, A12a, A12b, A12c, A21, A22, A23, A24, A25, A31, A31a, A31b, A32, A33, A33a, A33b, A33c, A34, A41, A42, A43, A51, A52, A53, A54, A54a, A54b, A54c, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, Z0, a.prog, a.utente, C11, D11, D13, D14, D14a, D14b, D14c, D15, D16, D17, D18, D19, D21, D22, D23, D31, D32, D41, D42, D43, D44, D45, Z1
FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B
WHERE SOME_CONDITION
ORDER BY a.a21 ASC, a.a03 ASC LIMIT 20000
```

The following code fragment issues the query:

```
    protected DataTable GetDataTableV1(string aSqlStatement)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

        using (DbContext dataContext = GetDataContext())
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = dataContext.Database.Connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = aSqlStatement;
                    using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dtResult.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dtResult;
    }
```

The query, run both in Workbench and SMSS, returns 1192 results in my case. That is fine. But when the app runs on MYSQL I get only 1156 results!

If I debug into `dtResult.Load(reader);` running on MySQL I get an unexpected behaviour (and only on MySQL): reader is made of 1192 results.

[image: DataReader screenshot]

Obviously, reading the DataReader from debug consumes it, so I can debug again into it.
Now it shows 1156 records!

[image: DataTable screenshot]

I have examined the result dataset thanks to an "Export to CSV" feature in the code. Remember that the query is ordered by fields `A21` and `A03` ascending? Looks like that while these fields are not part of primary key, unique, distinct or whatever, DataTable drops rows with matching pairs of them.

I mean that, analysing the resulting dataset, each and every row that **is present** in MS SQL dataset but **is missing** in the MySQL dataset shows the same exact pair of columns 1 and 3 of the screenshot below as the next. These columns are respectively `C` and `N` in my example. And, again, these columns are not part of the primary key

[image: Dataset fragment]

### My question is

Why does DataTable behave like this **only** on MySQL? How can I include the full result set in my DataTable?

Comment: are you sure it's nothing to do with the following -`ORDER BY a.a21 ASC, a.a03 ASC LIMIT 20000` not sure if the Query is handled the same in the 2 different DBMS have you tried it with selecting like `Top 1192` records, what if `LIMIT` works in My Sql and not Sql Server.. or vs versa...

Comment: Found a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229425/net-datatable-skips-rows-on-loaddatareader

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained well. The app translates the query to the correct LIMIT format. i.e. if it runs on SQL it puts a TOP 20000 after select, instead on Mysql it puts a LIMIT 20000 at the end. The WHERE condition is not modified

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification.. `using (IDataReader` for this line Use `DataReader instead of IDataReader` I am interested in seeing the difference if it works then I think I know the issue..

Comment: It generally works because MysqlDataReader inherits DataReader which implements IDataReader. Actually the interfaces are rarely used in ADO APIs

Comment: I know why.. but that's not why I was asking.. I think that your issue has to deal with IDataReader vs just using DataReader in regards of 2 different DBMS you are trying to access.. but then again I could be wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to wrap the whole query in a `SELECT` statement, exactly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23083491/471213)